# Java table in table with auto resize

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jscrollpane

I want to make a table witch can contain small tables and supports resize. [image]

My solution use a JScrollpane wich contains the table and the gridbaglayout contains the row which is a JPanel and this row JPanel contains JLabels and ETable (flowlayout).

How i can solve the resize problem? When i resize the window the column align automtically with the window.

My code is [here](http://pastebin.com/4k6PSDk2).

[image]

The columns are not aligned correctly in the big table.

Comment: Lets wait for trashgod or Hovercraft Full Of Eels!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I see there J(X)TreeTable or Outline with Custom Look and Feel (Renderer talking about Nimbus L&F, because isn't there correctly used background for Boolean value)
2. put JComponents (from top) top the JPanel and there use GridBagLayout
3. put JScrollPane with J(X)TreeTable or Outline put to the Center area
4. please which type of TreeTable is there used ??? (for calculating PreferredSize of Columns)

EDIT

> In this case replace the table with a black box. It's not relevant.

`JFrame` has implemented `BorderLayout` in the API, then

- all `JComponent`s from the `TOP of the JFrame` put to the separate `JPanel`, there you can use `GridBagLayout`, this `JPanel` put to the `NORTH area` e.g. `JFrame.add(JPanel, BorderLayout.NORHT)`
- put `black box` to the CENTER area e.g. `JFrame.add(black box, BorderLayout.CENTER)`

Comment: Also consider opening the sub-table in another container.

Comment: In this case replace the small table with a black box. It's not relevant. The big table is column alignment is the main problem when i resize the window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
Jtable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

using this `JTable` will display horizontal as well as vertical scroll bar when required.